# How to set enum to save value in database to int value , FastAPI and Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, enums, fastapi

so i try to make system for keep value like a premission.

- admin = 0
- edit = 1
- viewer = 2

i try to make model user like this.

```
#model.py
class User(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    username = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    password = Column(String)
    permission = Column(Enum(Permission))
```

and i migrat whit alembic (autogen).

```
def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('users',
    sa.Column('username', sa.String(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('password', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('permission', sa.Enum('Admin', 'Viewer', name='permission'), nullable=True),
```

my enum

```
from enum import Enum, IntEnum

class Permission(IntEnum):
    Admin = 0
    Edit = 1
    Viewer = 2
```

so where i save in postgres it save to admin in this code

```
#service.py
def create_user_with_admin_permission(db: SessionLocal, username: str, password: str):
    permission_value = Permission.Admin
    #at up this line i try to use Permission.Admin.value but not work
    user = models.User(username=username, password=password, permission=permission_value)
    db.add(user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(user)
    return user
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIGXi.png)

can u help me pls T_T
or i not sure if i save value on string like this image is good way or bad way.
i understand that recording in int is better.

something in the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now i fix by change tihs line

```
permission = Column(Enum(Permission))
```

to

```
permission = Column(Integer)
```